# Refactor Models of gems - pluralized variables in rake-task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm an early ruby dev so excuse me if this is obvious.

Using the gioco gem to implement a gamification concept I renamed a few classes and references to better fit in the project (tested everything and it's working).

The problematic rename is Kind => BadgeKind.

This line in the following task:

`r.points  << Point.create({ :badge_kind_id => kinds.id, :value => '#{args.points}'})`

**What's the concept behind `kinds.id` and how do I solve this?**

Error:
`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'kinds' for main:Object`

I tried: `badge_kind`, `badge_kinds`

Task:

```
task :add_badge, [:name, :points, :kind, :default] => :environment do |t, args|
arg_default = ( args.default ) ? eval(args.default) : false

if !args.name || !args.points || !args.kind
  raise "There are missing some arguments"
else
  badge_string = "kind = BadgeKind.find_or_create_by(name: '#{args.kind}')\n"

  badge_string = badge_string + "badge = Badge.create({ 
                  :name => '#{args.name}', 
                  :points => '#{args.points}',
                  :badge_kind_id  => kind.id,
                  :default => '#{arg_default}'
                })
"

  if arg_default
    # changing User.find(:all) to User.all
    badge_string = badge_string + 'resources = User.all
'
    badge_string = badge_string + "resources.each do |r|
    r.points  << Point.create({ :badge_kind_id => kinds.id, :value => '#{args.points}'})
      r.badges << badge
      r.save!
    end
"
  end

  badge_string = badge_string + "puts '> Badge successfully created'"

  # puts "badge_string:\n" + badge_string
  eval badge_string
end
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using eval?

Comment: This code is not mine. It's from the gioco gem. I just replaced a few identifiers.

Comment: No need to snark, maxcal. MINASWAN, remember? Eval is dangerous because someone might be able to pass in a well crafted string to a form on your site and start arbitrarily executing code on your server, so we don't use that method. It sounds like it wasn't your code anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have tables in your application for `Kind` and `Badge`. If that's the case, then it's not a good idea to rename `Badge` to `BadgeKind`. The reason is because this notation is commonly used for join tables, and it looks like you might be colliding with one. Right now, I'm guessing a `Badge` can have a `Kind` or vice versa. In order to make that happen, there may be a `BadgeKind` table that contains their relationships. I can't tell for sure without seeing your schema file or migrations, but you're probably better off leaving that the way it is, or at least choosing a different name like `BadgeType`.

Also, it's worth noting that building up strings to be executed with eval is considered an antipattern. Eval is slow, and also exposes your application to malicious code injection. You're at less of a risk because it appears this is a rake task, but even so, if you refactor this code, you should try a different strategy. It looks like it would be relatively straightforward to refactor.